# React conditional rendering not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm having an issue with conditional rendering where I'm making a get request to the jsonplaceholder and storing the result in the state via setState, as I loop through every object and render the result to the browser, I'm getting this error:  **"Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."**

here's the code snippet for that :

**fetching results from jsonplaceholder**

```
state = {
    people: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(response => {
      this.setState({ people: response.data });
    });
  }
```

**Displaying it on the screen**

```
render() {
    if (this.state.people) {
      this.state.people.map(person => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>{person.name}</h1>
            <h2>{person.username}</h2>
            <p>{person.email}</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result created by .map function which is an array.

```
     render() {
            if (this.state.people) {
              return <>
              {this.state.people.map(person => 

                  <React.Fragment>
                    <h1>{person.name}</h1>
                    <h2>{person.username}</h2>
                    <p>{person.email}</p>
                  </React.Fragment>

              )}
              </>
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty array [is considered truthy in javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) (try running `!![]` in console). So when your component mounts with an empty array as the initial state your render function will not return anything.

If you replace `if(this.state.people)` with `if(this.state.people.length > 0)` then you should get the expected behaviour.